# Question about output from hmmdecode in matlab

Tags: matlab

Why is it the case, that if I have a sequence of length N which I give as `seq` input to `hmmdecode`, it will give me a BACKWARD and FORWARD-output which indicates that I have N+1 time-points?

I expected an output that indiciated that I have N time-points/observationssequence of length N.